# Use alternative location for .idea folder?

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm

In our project there is `.idea` folder checked-in into git repository with old content
(there is even [.iml file that is actually previous generation](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems)),
and it puts project into dirty state right after import.

While ultimate  solution will be to remove `.idea` folder completely,
is there a way to **configure alternative location for IDE `.idea` folder**,
so that when I work on the project current `.idea` folder is not used and not modified.

[image: .idea content]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to **configure alternative location for IDE `.idea` folder**, so that when I work on the project current `.idea` folder is not used and not modified?

Yes, you can keep your `.idea` elsewhere.

**Please note:**

- I will be using PhpStorm as an IDE (JetBrains IDE I'm using). It has simple project config (where the project consists of a single module of `WEB_MODULE` type; the same applies to WebStorm) while Java/Python/Ruby one have more complicated project settings (where it's normal (especially for Java world) to have multiple modules per project).
- I'm not sure how easy it is to change this for *existing project* (it's not a problem for a new project). Might be possible to do manually by editing the config files directly, but cannot guarantee that it will not have some side effects (especially if it's multi-module one, while the IDE is closed of course).

  So it's much better to go with a new project and configure it from scratch (most of the config files can be copied over from old `.idea` into the new one).

##### Anyway, the overall idea is as follows:

1. In your IDE, create a new project where you want to keep your `.idea` -- lets assume this will be `C:\JetBrainsProjectsStore\MyProject`.
2. Go to the project settings and find a place where you configure your Content Roots. In PhpStorm/WebStorm this will be `Settings/Preferences | Directories`.
3. Remove existing Content Root (by default every project has one). In our example this will be the aforementioned `C:\JetBrainsProjectsStore\MyProject` folder.
4. Add a New Content Root instead: point it to the folder where your project files actually are (or where you want to keep them). Lets assume this will be `C:\Projects\MyActualProject`.
5. Save. That's it (well, repeat steps 3-4 for other modules if your project has them).

Now your project config is stored in `C:\JetBrainsProjectsStore\MyProject\.idea` while the actual code files are in `C:\Projects\MyActualProject`.

Obviously, if you now need to use `Open` in the IDE to open a project or open it from the command line, you need to use the parent folder where the actual `.idea` is -- `C:\JetBrainsProjectsStore\MyProject`.

---

There is a ticket that asks for the same: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170102. Watch it (star/vote/comment) to get notified with any progress.

Comment: The ticket you linked to doesn't exists and I wasn't able to find any with that issue-id.

Comment: Sorry. Somehow added an extra `2` to the ticket number.

Comment: No worries. I was curious about the use cases and they're all ones that seem like they're trying to solve a different problem. Namely, not checking in project files. There's the 'clearcase' outlier, but that's a whole different set of problems. *shrug*.  Thanks again for the link!

Answer (score 0):

'No'. The `.idea` folder is specific to Jetbrains IDEA applications (Intellij, Webstorm, etc..) and is used to configure your IDE per your workstation environment or shared developer settings.

That being said, you do have options:

- If you're the only person on your team using Jetbrains tools, you can safely add the folder to your `.gitignore` file. That will stop git (and IDEA) from monitoring or caring about changes.
- Jetbrains has guidance on what each file is for and which ones you might consider [checking in to your VCS](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839) and they have a default `.gitignore` you can use [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Global/JetBrains.gitignore)
- You could also setup a symlink to a different directory if you really wanted to. However, that comes with some risks in terms of backing up files and I think `git` will still see those file changes. You would definitely want to add `.idea` to your `.gitignore` then, as other developers won't have the same folder structure and the symlink will 'break' for them.

Comment: While these are all good thoughts, it is not answering question. And it looks like you have not read it.

Comment: The 'no' is in quotation marks to suggest that while you technically can, you probably shouldn't. I then provided you several methods by which you can re-locate your .idea folder or achieve what seems to be your end goal: to not have git "puts project into dirty state right after import." and "so that when I work on the project current .idea folder is not used and not modified".  Regardless of where you move the .idea folder, it is intrinsic to the operation of the IDEA family of applications and will not remain 'unmodified' while using them.

Comment: @LazyOne has provided yet another way that you can change the location of that folder, but, as someone using Jetbrains products for ~15 years, I would discourage moving that folder. It often leads to more headaches and overhead, requiring you to be dilligent about maintaining that new folder location and its contents since it won't be removed when you delete your project folder and will likely end up out of date if you try to re-create the project. It sounds like you're trying to avoid polluting the teams project space and the best path to that is to use the .gitignore guidance.